# populating value in scala datafarme from one cell to the other cells below it

Tags: scala, dataframe

I have a table as shown below

```
Type Name Weight
t1  n1  12
    n1  23
    n1  54
    n1  23
    n1  43
    n1  23
    n1  76
t2  n2  34
    n2  12
    n2  43
    n2  21
t3  n3  4
    n3  67
    n3  23
    n3  34
    n3  23
    n3  12
    n3  56
    n3  67
    n3  89
t4  n4  65
    n5  34
    n6  32
```

I want to populate the value in column **Type** to all cells below it until new **Type** value shown, as shown below

```
Type Name Weight
t1  n1  12
t1  n1  23
t1  n1  54
t1  n1  23
t1  n1  43
t1  n1  23
t1  n1  76
t2  n2  34
t2  n2  12
t2  n2  43
t2  n2  21
t3  n3  4
t3  n3  67
t3  n3  23
t3  n3  34
t3  n3  23
t3  n3  12
t3  n3  56
t3  n3  67
t3  n3  89
t4  n4  65
t4  n5  34
t4  n6  32
```

Using regular `for` loop with this table is not a good idea, because I am working with table of millions of records and 100+ columns.

Thanks in advance